# static constant class data member setter and getter

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class level data member

```
class T{
 Static const double PI;
```

this data member, **static const double PI**, should have value of 3.141593.

The value I know can be set outside main() using class resolution operator :: as it is static const and not an integer.

Can this variable have setter and getter?

If this variable has setter, won't it give error upon using it, as const cannot be set values again and again?

Comment: You are right it can not have a setter, why do you think this const variable could have one?

Comment: `class T { public: inline static constexpr double PI = 3.141516; };`

Comment: You seem to be using the same verb "set" to mean two different things: "initialize" and "assign to"; and this leads to confusion. A `const` variable can, and in fact needs to, be initialized, in exactly one place in the program; but it cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Non of the member variables should have setters and getters at all, that whole idea is profanation of OOP.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to the question, but why would you want your class to define the **wrong** value of π? (The *actual* value to the precision you have specified is 3.141593.)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. This question is answered! You are right we should not have the setter etc at all!

Comment: Fixed PI's value

Comment: ... and you should use [`std::numbers::pi_v<double>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) instead of defining your own.